# Excel VSTO calculating Range size

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm writing a performance critical (isn't everything) add-in for Excel using VSTO and as part of that I'm wrapping up the Excel functionality so that I do not always end up with `dynamic` returns from the base VSTO interfaces.

One of my wrappers is for the `Range` interface and for this I'm calculating a Rectangle which describes the top left and bottom right cell based on the `Range` to wrap up. The `Range` may be simply one cell or could be the used range of the current worksheet.

So my code to calculate the top left coordinate looks like...

```
var x = excelRange.Column;
var y = excelRange.Row;
```

and to calculate the bottom right coordinate looks like...

```
var columnsCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;
var rowsCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;

var x = columnsCount * topLeftCoordinate.X;
var y = rowsCount * topLeftCoordinate.Y;
```

This is nice and simple and I assumed would also be relatively pain free in terms of performance as I wouldn't want to request these values from the `Range` interface multiple times.

Unfortunately after profiling my application and creating 2631 rectangles in varying sizes, from 1x1 to 10x1, I can see that simply calculating these values takes up around 18%/600ms of my application time all of which are in the calls to the VSTO `Range` interface.

Is there another way of getting the range size without requiring 4 calls to the `Range` interface or am I better to simply refactor my code so that for 1x1 ranges I don't calculate a rectangle for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do fewer calls by querying range address:

```
string address = excelRange.Address; //Now you get address like "$A1$10"(single cell) or "$A$23:$Z$78"(multiple cells)
```

All you need is to parse address string, and that is for sure much faster than doing 5 more calls to interop wrappers. In my tests it was 2-3 times faster at the end.

One more thing not related to question - don't forget to check for Areas in Range, as range may consist of multiple ranges(multiple area selection).

Comment: This was something that I had considered before I implemented it the way I had, but it had created an extra issue in that to convert the string representation of the `Address` to indexes (as I use the `Range` limits to index into an array from elsewhere) didn't seem to be worth the hassle since it is quite easy to get some `int`'s from the interface.It looks like this may be the way that I have to go just to cut down on the number of calls across the interop.